# "java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter" error on released apk

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I was setting up notifications in a flutter app using the flutter local notifications plugin. This is the code for it.

```
 await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
        Duration(
            seconds: 40,
            minutes: timeinminpicked - timeinminNow - 1,
            days: pickedDate!.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays),
        0,
        addalarm,
        alarmClock: true,
        wakeup: true,
        exact: true,
        allowWhileIdle: true);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();

    await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().zonedSchedule(
        0,
        todoController.text,
        'Tap to turn OFF',
        tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(
            seconds: 30,
            minutes: timeinminpicked - timeinminNow - 1,
            days: pickedDate!.difference(DateTime.now()).inDays)),
        const NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id',
                'your channel name', 'your channel description')),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
```

While running it on debug mode on VS code, the notification came on time but when i tried it on released apk/ using flutter run --release, the app stopped abruptly. This was the error which appeared :

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Missing type parameter., null, java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
E/flutter ( 8874):      at c.b.a.O.a.<init>(:3)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.a.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.loadScheduledNotifications(Unknown Source:25)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.saveScheduledNotification(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedScheduleNotification(:2)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(:2)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:255)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at d.a.d.a.q.a(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.l.g.c(Unknown Source:25)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown Source:4)      
E/flutter ( 8874):      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:182)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)   
E/flutter ( 8874):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
E/flutter ( 8874): )
E/flutter ( 8874): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597)
E/flutter ( 8874): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158)E/flutter ( 8874): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8874): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:137)
E/flutter ( 8874): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8874): #3      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:300)
E/flutter ( 8874): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8874): #4      _BottomMSheetState.sumbitData (package:reminder/Widgets/BottomMsheet.dart:81)       
E/flutter ( 8874): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8874):
I/flutter ( 8874): [{id: 2021-07-06 12:17:17.609807, title: hahB, date: Tue,6/7/2021, time: 12:18}, {id: 2021-07-06 12:18:26.093092, title: hello, date: Tue,6/7/2021, time: 12:19}]
```

This is my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.reminder">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
   <application
        android:label="reminder"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <service
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"
      />
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Please help me understand what's wrong. PS: I'm a flutter newbie and not accustomed to java.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of compression,so either disable compression using R8/fullmode on R8 on gradle 8+

Or You can write proguard rules to prevent along with having compression (recomended)

See example app for reference

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro

and I think for new projects there may be some changes required based on Kotlin version,gradle settings, etc in such cases search developer documentation of Android or comment here.